# Need to provide multiple file download functionality for clients - Amazon S3 storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Amazon S3 storage for my files and i need to provide download functionality in which user can select multiple files and download them at once (as dropbox)...

I tried to implement this functionality by downloading each file in memory stream and create a zip file and returned to user, but its too much time consuming, I need to know that is there any way that this process can be implemented asynchronously that user don't have to be wait longer and downloading starts immediately as dropbox do...

I am using MVC Web API...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

From a high level, I would probably do something like this.

Trigger a job with the file set the user wants to download. Have a worker that downloads the files from s3, compresses them into a zip file and then uploads it back to a temporary location in s3.

Once the job is completed, send the user a signed URL to the zip file itself.

Clean up the zip file after a certain amount of time. Maybe 24 hours?

Comment: there isn't any fixed set of files, user may select random files to be download every time...

Comment: @kami998 That will be fine. You pass the file set into the job parameters.